# How can I make small circles in a java TUI?

Tags: java, tui

I am making a board game with a simple TUI and I am trying to display the board on the screen. It's kind of like tic-tac-toe, except that what you place one the board are black or white disks. I wanted to have the black disks be an O (this would work since the run window background is black), but I can't find a way to display just a white circle or a filled in circle, rather.

I was hoping that there was some way I could do all that using something like System.out.println(), because I don't really have time to start making a GUI. I've been looking online for a while and can't find anything.

If anyone knows how to do this or a better way of doing things, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your output console supports Unicode well (basically a given on Linux and I believe Mac, possible but tricky to set up on Windows), you can just use `\u2B24` in a string to print [U+2B24](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2B24).

Comment: Or for an outlined circle use ◯ [U+25EF](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+25EF)

Comment: `O` and `X`? `O` and `#`?